# How to only paste visible cells in an email body

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I am trying to copy an entire sheet into an email body and the sheet is already filtered and hides rows. I want to copy only the visible rows into the email. I thought my code would do that but when the people reply to the emails, the entire sheet (both hidden and unhidden) appears in the email. Any ideas?

```
Sub Send_Range_Or_Whole_Worksheet_with_MailEnvelope()
'Working in Excel 2002-2013
    Dim AWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim Sendrng As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    On Error GoTo StopMacro

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    'Fill in the Worksheet/range you want to mail
    'Note: if you use one cell it will send the whole worksheet
    Set Sendrng = Worksheets("Test").Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    'Remember the activesheet
    Set AWorksheet = ActiveSheet

    With Sendrng

        ' Select the worksheet with the range you want to send
        .Parent.Select

        'Remember the ActiveCell on that worksheet
        Set rng = ActiveCell

        'Select the range you want to mail
        .Select

        ' Create the mail and send it
        ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
        With .Parent.MailEnvelope

            ' Set the optional introduction field thats adds
            ' some header text to the email body.
            .Introduction = "Test"

            With .Item
                .To = "test@email.com"
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = "Test"
                .Send
            End With

        End With

        'select the original ActiveCell
        rng.Select
    End With
```

This was essentially taken from [this Example 2 of Ron de Bruin](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail3.htm), with some code from [another example](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm).

Comment: Is it mandatory to send with envelope, or is it ok for you to create an email and paste your data in the body?

Comment: That would be fine I think. I honestly don't know what you mean. I'm a very novice vba user, mostly piece things together from googling...

Comment: Good enough. Please check the code posted.

Comment: Did you find useful any of what was posted?

Answer (score 0):

The code below seems to work.
You will have to fill it in with `Range`s selection/activation and other details as needed.

**EDIT** The final step is sending the email (as per an added request of the OP). `DoEvents` added thanks to an answer to [Excel VBA: Sent Outlook email does not include pasted Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20963032/excel-vba-sent-outlook-email-does-not-include-pasted-range)

```
Sub SendEmail()

    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    'Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim MItem As Object
    'Dim MItem As Outlook.MailItem

    'Create Outlook object
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    'Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application

    Dim Sendrng As Range
    Set Sendrng = Worksheets("Test").Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Sendrng.Copy

    'Create Mail Item
    Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    'Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With MItem
        .To = "test@email.com"
        .Subject = "Test"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        '.Body = "a"
        .Display
    End With
    SendKeys "^({v})", True
    DoEvents
    With MItem
        .Send
    End With

    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
    Set MItem = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: This is great and appears to solve my problem! However, the email does not send automatically as part of the code? Is there a way to add that?

Comment: Actually, I figured it out. Change .Display to .Send. However, it is not pasting the selection in the body. It was hit or miss, but now its not pasting anything in...

Comment: @user3009860 - The change you propose is not the way to do it. Please check updated code, and give feedback on what you find.

Answer (score -1):

Since you did not state it is mandatory to use VBA (at least when this answer was first posted), you might:

Go to Home -> Find & Select -> Go To Special -> Visible cells only. Then copy and paste into your email. That worked for me.

Comment: I posted another solution based on VBA then.