# Excel VBA: Sent Outlook email does not include pasted Range

Tags: vba, email, excel, outlook

I have [initially answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20955476/2707864) question [How to only paste visible cells in an email body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861607/how-to-only-paste-visible-cells-in-an-email-body)

The code I tested and posted (see below) did not include sending email. After the OP added that to his question, I added the `.Send` part, but the behavior I obtained is very strange.
If I place a breakpoint just before sending, and I execute the `Sub`, an email is created with the correct info (including the pasted Excel `Range`). Then I continue execution and the email is correctly sent. But if I run the whole `Sub` at once, with no breakpoints, the email is sent with no pasted Excel `Range` in the body.

What is the reason for that, and what is the solution?

I have tried commenting/uncommenting the two last lines (`Set ... = Nothing`), but it does not help.

---

Related questions:

[Copy range of cells from Excel to body of email in Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757381/copy-range-of-cells-from-excel-to-body-of-email-in-outlook)

[Pasting formatted Excel range into Outlook message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512351/pasting-formatted-excel-range-into-outlook-message)

---

Code of reference (based on the quintessential code by Ron de Bruin, see [this](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail3.htm) and [this](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm)):

```
Sub SendEmail()

    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    'Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim MItem As Object
    'Dim MItem As Outlook.MailItem

    'Create Outlook object
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    'Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application

    Dim Sendrng As Range
    Set Sendrng = Worksheets("Test").Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Sendrng.Copy

    'Create Mail Item
    Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    'Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With MItem
        .To = "test@email.com"
        .To = "SSEREBRINSKY@TENARIS.COM"
        .Subject = "Test"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        '.Body = "a"
        .Display
    End With
    SendKeys "^({v})", True
    With MItem
        .Send
    End With

    'Set OutlookApp = Nothing
    'Set MItem = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But if I run the whole Sub at once, with no breakpoints, the email is sent with no pasted Excel Range in the body. What is the reason for that, and what is the solution?

The reason is pretty simple. When you use breakpoint, you are giving Excel enough time for a copy paste. `SendKeys` hence are very unreliable when working with other applications.

There are many ways to solve your problem. One is to give enough time for a copy paste. You can do that by using `DoEvents` or forcing a `Wait Time`. For example

```
SendKeys "^({v})", True
DoEvents
```

Or

```
SendKeys "^({v})", True
Wait 2 '<~~ Wait for 2 seconds
```

and use this sub in your code

```
Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Long)
    nSec = nSec + Timer
    While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```

BTW, instead of using `SendKeys` you can use the `RangetoHTML` function by Ron de Bruin as shown [HERE](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm)

**EDIT**

If the above doesn't work then that means `SendKeys` is getting executed too fast in that case, use `DoEvents/Wait` right after `.Display` as well.

```
.Display
DoEvents
```

Or

```
.Display
Wait 2
```

Comment: +1: I second using the exact code for pasting the `Range` you want into the body. This is what I use as well. The only big downside to it is the `Body` gets converted to `HTMLBody`, which limits some things you want to do (and changes the default mail font to Times New Roman for me, icky but quite easy to solve).

Comment: @BK201: True :) One can always use `SendMessage` API ;)

Comment: Something new to learn everyday. Will read up on this `SendMessage` API. Looks promising, and it might even solve this issue I have with sending charts and graphs to the mail body. ;)

Comment: I confirm that only adding a `DoEvents` after `SendKeys` was enough. I suspected it had to do with some (unwanted) fast processing of the email, but I did not know about `DoEvents` (see [documentation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/118468)). Awesome.

Comment: + 1 I can only see your answers everywhere :)